# Bootstrap4 Update on VS2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, bootstrap-4

I had updated the bootstrap package to version 4 thru NuGet. I am not sure why but I keep getting errors and warnings, mostly build errors like 'CSS property not known' or 'Expected RBRACE' on, line numbers where braces don't make sense. It has never happened before. Any thoughts?

[css files indicated wit squiggly lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGK1C.png)
[build errors and warnings when hovered over the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhpSY.png)

Comment: Are you using some CSS linter?

Comment: Not that i know of..